# Entitlement Management Disappearance

Tags: apex, visualforce, entitlements

Early sometime today or late last night, Entitlement Management, and every related object like Service Contracts disappeared, along with all their records, etc. I had many visualforce and Apex classes that used the Service Contract object. What's weird is that I can't even see it on the setup screen under customize, it's like the objects/section never existed at all.

Has anyone seen this happen before, where an object just disappears, I've gone through login logs/every System Admin, every profile/role looking at permissions looking for a culprit, and I just do not have an explanation for what caused it. I've contacted support, but I'm looking everywhere for a solution.

Comment: Is there anything in the trash? Did your instance get changed somehow?  Salesforce notes that, "Only users in organizations with the Service Cloud can enable, create, and update entitlement management items."

Comment: I thought of that (the Service Cloud, that is), I believe that was the culprit, though I'm unsure. I contacted support, and the objects were restored over the weekend. I think it may have just been a mistake as I know we renewed our license quite recently however, they never actually told us what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens to anyone in the future, contact support as soon as possible, as it is probable that something about your license/instance was modified (by them). I can't say for certainty that is the cause, but at the very least they will be able to solve the issue.